# Assembly division more decimal numbers remainders than just one

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, division

How am I supposed to get more division numbers in Assembly?

I can only print the first decimal number :c

```
org 100h ;start

xor edx,edx 
mov eax,1 
mov ebx,7 
div ebx ; 1 / 7  
; EAX / EBX = EAX; remainder IN EDX
; EDX VALUE IS ONLY 1 INSTEAD OF 1428571428571429‬....
; SO instead of printing 0,1428571428571429‬...x 
;(x is how many decimal numbers I want) I can only print out 0,1 :(

mov ax,4c00h;end
int 21h
```

Comment: Note that `div` gives you the remainder, not a decimal place.  It's a coincidence that this number is equal to the first decimal place in your case.  Try long division.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I'm new to assembly, so should I use a function or a loop?

Comment: Use whatever you need to solve the problem.  If you are unsure, try to sketch the algorithm in a high level language first and then translate it into assembly.

Comment: Instruction `div` performs **integer** division, in you example it gives quotient EAX=0 and remainder EDX=1. If you need **real** division, define numbers in memory as float `divident DD 1.0` and `divisor DD 7.0` and then use https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fdiv:fdivp:fidiv

Answer (score 2):

The integer division `div` looses the fraction from calculating 1/7 because it can only store the integer part of the result in the `EAX` register.

It is possible to print the result from calculating 1/7 with 9 decimal places and still only use integer operations. Just scale it up a bit and rather calculate 1000000000/7.

```
    ORG     256

    mov     eax, 1000000000
    mov     ebx, 7
    xor     edx, edx
    div     ebx          ; -> EAX = 142857142 EDX=6
; Rounding to nearest
    shr     ebx
    cmp     ebx, edx
    adc     eax, 0
; Converting to decimal characters
    mov     ebx, 10
    push    bx           ; Sentinel
  NextDiv:
    xor     edx, edx
    div     ebx
    add     dl, '0'
    push    dx
    test    eax, eax
    jnz     NextDiv
; Printing the result
    mov     ah, 02h      ; DOS.PrintChar
    mov     dl, '0'
    int     21h
    mov     dl, '.'
    int     21h
    pop     dx
  NextChar:
    int     21h
    pop     dx
    cmp     dx, bx
    jne     NextChar
; Giving yourself an opportunity to see the result
    mov     ah, 00h      ; BIOS.GetKey
    int     16h
; Quiting the program
    mov     ax, 4C00h    ; DOS.Terminate
    int     21h
```

The above program will print:

> 0.142857143
>   ‬